# Save a lot of file excel as rda using R

Tags: r, excel, loops

I have 1000 file excel with the name "1.xlsx" "2.xlsx" ... "1000.xlsx". Then how can i write a loop to save them as "1.rda" "2.rda" ... "1000.rda" without using this code 1000 times

> j1 <- read.xlsx("1.xlsx",1)
>
> save(j1, file = "j1.rda")

**Thanks a lot**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
library(tidyverse)
xlsx_to_rda <- function(inputname, outputname){
  save(read.xlsx(inputname,1), file = outputname)
}
walk2(paste0(1:1000, ".xlsx"),
      paste0(1:1000, ".rda"),
      xlsx_to_rda)
```

By the way rds would be a better file format, because it stores just one r object.

Comment: `save(j1, ` how does this work? Can you explain where `j1` is coming from?

Comment: @AaronP thanks for your help, but can you tell me how and when to use walk2 function

Comment: @PoGibas oh it's just a name i use in my project

Comment: @PoGibas yes j1 is wrong there, I changed it to the right 'temp'

Comment: @P.Nguyen there are multiple way's how you can repeat things in R. for loops are commonly used (in other languages), but they are not really the way to go in R. Instead R has a family of functions that do that. This is the apply family. They will iterate over some object and apply some function. Out of personal preference I use the purrr package (included in tidyverse) that try to replace the apply family.

Comment: walk is a function from the purrr package, that is specificly designed for functions that do not return anything (in sense of an object), but do something (like saving, plotting etc.) walk2 is a function that iterate over two objects at the same time. If you are interested in more information this is a good ressource:
http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html

Comment: @PoGibas I removed temp/j1 completly

Comment: @P.Nguyen if my answer ansered your question it would be nice if you accept it.

Comment: @AaronP oh it helps me a lot. Thank you so much

Comment: @P.Nguyen then you might consider accepting it (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)